# first order taylor expansion of -ln(1+x)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

This is what i have done so far but i think what i have done is incorrect. I am also referring to some other notes by my professor and they say that the correct answer should be -ln(1+x)
[image]

Comment: Hint: Expand $\ln (1-x)$, then exchange $x \mapsto -x.$

Comment: i got this https://imgur.com/a/hoXiWeL . I am a little lost still? Whats the hint?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = -\ln(1+x)$.

Taylor series expansion of $f$ around $x=t$

$f(x) = f(t) + f'(t)(x-t) + \ldots = -\ln(1+t) - \frac{1}{1+t}(x-t) +\ldots$.

The only case the answer is "$-\ln(1+t)$" is if you expand to zeroth order around $x=t$.

In the special case we expand around zero, we get

$f(x) =  -\ln(1+0) - \frac{1}{1+0}(x-0) +\ldots = 0-x + \ldots = -x +\ldots$

Comment: I am sorry i messed up i meant -ln(1+x)

Comment: @ujjwaltyagi: so you expand around x=0?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this.

The first:
$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac {f''(0)}{2}x^2 + \frac {f'''(0)}{3!}x^2+\cdots$

Start taking derivatives, look for a pattern, prove that the pattern holds.

$f(0) = 0\\
f'(x) = -\frac 1{1+x} = -(1+x)^{-1}\\
f''(x) = (1+x)^{-2}\\
f''(x) = -2(1+x)^{-3}\\
f^{(n)} = (-1)^n (n-1)!(1+x)^{-n-1}$

Prove that last line by induction.  Evaluate each at $x=0$ and plug into the formula above.

The slightly tricky way:

The sum of a geometric series:
$\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac {1}{1-x}\\  
f'(x) = -\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n\\
f(x) = \int_0^x -\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty (-x)^n\ dt$

Comment: shouldnt f(0) be -ln(1) because only x becomes 0 in -ln(1+x)

Comment: what is $-\ln(1)$?

Comment: Oh i understand!